# Area of the region of the complex plane enclosed between two paths

Tags: geometry, parametric

Suppose ${\cal U}\subset\mathbb C$ is a complex domain and $\gamma_0,\gamma_1 : [0,1]\to {\cal U}$ are two piecewise $\mathscr C^1$ paths, sharing the same start and end points, i.e. $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_0(0), \gamma_1(1)=\gamma_0(1)$. Is there a way to compute the area of the region enclosed between $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$?

Comment: I doubt that there is a general way. What does enclosed mean?

Comment: Yes, if they are homotopic and you have an analytical expression of the homotopy.

Comment: @copper.hat I think a slightly roundabout way to define the "enclosed region" would be to concatenate $\gamma_1^-$ and $\gamma_0$, with $\gamma_1^- : t\in [0,1] \mapsto\gamma_1(1-t)$. This defines a loop, which splits the rest of the complex plane into an interior (not necessarily connected) region and an exterior region.

Comment: Seeing the curves as lying in $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead, then if it would be possible to write $\gamma_1(t) = (c(t), d_1(t))$ and $\gamma_2(t) = (c(t), d_2(t))$ (the same $c(t),$ this is the most important fact), then the area enclosed by the two curves would be $A = \int_{c(0)}^{c(1)} \vert \delta_2(x) - \delta_1(x) \vert dx,$ where $\delta_i(x) = d_i(t)$ when $c(t) = x$ assuming this gives a unique solution.

Comment: @KCJV So, the complement of the unbounded region defined by the loop?

Comment: @ActuallyFritz I agree, though as you mentioned there is the need for $\delta_i(x)=d_i(t)$ to have a unique solution

Comment: @copper.hat Yes